# How to change bin width on R highcharter histogram

Tags: r, highcharts

In the basic example of the histogram generated by R highcharter package that is:

```
hchart(diamonds$price)
```

the bin width is automatically set to 200. I tried few datasets and the bin width vary. That makes me think that this is somehow set automatically. How can I set it manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`hchart`is a generic function which work with `histogram` classes too. Try following:

```
library(highcharter)
data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")

h <- hist(diamonds$price, plot = FALSE)
hchart(h)


h2 <- hist(diamonds$price, breaks = 100, plot = FALSE)
hchart(h2)
```

So, you can create the histogram what you want using the base `hist` function, then you can chart it with highcharter.